# The connection to the database will be closed correctly? psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have used this code for ~10 days and it worked just fine. Today it crashed with an error message:

> File "/home/ubuntu/jag-bot/utils/db.py", line 22, in check_user
> with self.connection:
> psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Code:

```
@dataclass
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(config.DB_URI, sslmode='require')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.current_date = utc.localize(datetime.now())

    def check_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM mango WHERE user_id = {user_id}")
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            return True
        return False
```

**UPDATE:**
Fixed with error handling.
Do I need this line 'self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()' in except block?

```
def check_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            with self.connection:
                self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM mango WHERE user_id = {user_id}")
        except psycopg2.InterfaceError as exc:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(DB_URI)
            # self.cursor = self.connection.cursor() What about this string?
            with self.connection:
                self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM mango WHERE user_id = {user_id}")
        finally:
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue that has been fixed by the maintainers of Jagster. Please update your database module to version 0.1.5 or higher from PyPI. You can find instructions on how to do so here: https://github.com/Jagster-Bot/Jagster-Bot/issues/1218

Comment: The link does not exist. Please fix it or delete the answer.

Comment: GPT before it was cool